# XSLT apply-templates inside for-each

Tags: templates, xslt, foreach, match, apply-templates

I have an XSLT like below, and want to use `apply-templates` inside the `xsl:for-each` element so I don't have to repeat the `<tr>` element with the informations of the "`cliente`" XML element.

I'm trying but with no success to create a `xsl:template` and put `xsl:apply-templates` inside the `xsl:for-each`.

I know that I can use `xsl:call-template`, but is there any way to use `xsl:apply-templates` inside or outside the `for-each`?

Any idea on how to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head><title>Informações</title></head>
         <body>
            <h1>Relação de Clientes</h1>
            <table border="2">
               <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
                  <th>Nome</th>
                  <th>Telefone</th>
                  <th>Cidade</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Crédito</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightPink">Critério usado abaixo: exibir todos os elementos ordenado por nome</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
               <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
                  <tr>
                     <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightCyan"> Critério usado abaixo: exibir os clientes da cidade do Rio de Janeiro</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
                   <xsl:if test="cidade='Rio de Janeiro'">
                      <tr>
                         <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
                         <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
                         <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
                         <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
                         <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes do estado do RJ com ordenado pelo nome; </th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
               <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
               <xsl:if test="estado='RJ'">
                  <tr>
                     <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes com crédito entre 250 e 400, em ordem descendente de crédito) </th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
               <xsl:sort select="credito" order="descending" />
               <xsl:if test="credito&gt;250 and credito&lt;400">
                  <tr>
                     <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </table>
            </body>
         </html>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of your `xsl:for-each` where you are iterating over `informacoes/cliente`, the context node will be the current `cliente` element.

**In order to `apply-templates` for the context node, you can use `.` in your select statement.** For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
  <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then, create templates to match the `cliente` element:

```
<xsl:template match="informacoes/cliente">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**You could also eliminate the `<xsl:if>` tests surrounding some of your items by referring to the current context node using the `self::` axis and then applying the test criteria inside of a predicate filter on the context node:**

```
  <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
     <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[estado='RJ']"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Applying these changes to your example stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Informações</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>Relação de Clientes</h1>
                <table border="2">
                    <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Telefone</th>
                        <th>Cidade</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Crédito</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightPink">Critério usado abaixo: exibir todos os elementos ordenado por nome</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
                        <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightCyan"> Critério usado abaixo: exibir os clientes da cidade do Rio de Janeiro</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[cidade='Rio de Janeiro']"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes do estado do RJ com ordenado pelo nome; </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
                        <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[estado='RJ']"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes com crédito entre 250 e 400, em ordem descendente de crédito) </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">
                        <xsl:sort select="credito" order="descending" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[credito&gt;250 and credito&lt;400]"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="informacoes/cliente">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As demonstrated in Dimitre Novatchev's answer, you can further simplify your stylesheet by eliminating the `xsl:for-each` statements and adjusting your `xsl:apply-templates` select statements; applying an `xsl:sort` inside of the apply-templates where necessary to ensure the selected `cliente` elements are processed in the desired order.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[estado='RJ']">
  <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, Mads!! I understood perfectly well. The self:: tip is also very good! Thanks again!

Comment: Downvoting this answer, because although it works and answers the question, using `<for-each select=x><apply-templates select="."/></for-each>` is quite unnecessary, as it's equivalent to `<apply-templates select=x/>`.

Comment: @Michael Kay - point taken. Agreed that it would be more simple and easy to eliminate the `xsl:for-each`. Was attempting to answer the question of how, but neglected to include a suggestion for a better and more simple way to achieve results.

Answer (score 3):

**Just replace**:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente"> 
           <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" /> 
              <tr> 
                 <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td> 
              </tr> 
           </xsl:for-each>
```

**With**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente">
  <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Similarly, replace**:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">       
               <xsl:if test="cidade='Rio de Janeiro'">       
                  <tr>       
                     <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>       
                     <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>       
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>       
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>       
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>       
                  </tr>       
                </xsl:if>       
            </xsl:for-each>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[cidade='Rio de Janeiro']"/>
```

**Similarly, replace**:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">           
           <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />           
           <xsl:if test="estado='RJ'">           
              <tr>           
                 <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>           
                 <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>           
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>           
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>           
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>           
              </tr>           
            </xsl:if>           
              </xsl:for-each>
```

**with:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[estado='RJ']">
  <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**And finally replace**:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="informacoes/cliente">               
           <xsl:sort select="credito" order="descending" />               
           <xsl:if test="credito&gt;250 and credito&lt;400">               
              <tr>               
                 <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>               
                 <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>               
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>               
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>               
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>               
              </tr>               
            </xsl:if>               
              </xsl:for-each>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[credito >250 and 400 > credito]">
  <xsl:sort select="credito" order="descending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Then add this simple template**:

```
<xsl:template match="informacoes/cliente">
 <tr>               
  <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>               
  <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>               
  <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>               
  <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>               
  <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>               
 </tr>               
</xsl:template>
```

**Your complete XSLT code now becomes this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head><title>Informações</title></head>
         <body>
            <h1>Relação de Clientes</h1>
            <table border="2">
               <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
                  <th>Nome</th>
                  <th>Telefone</th>
                  <th>Cidade</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Crédito</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightPink">Critério usado abaixo: exibir todos os elementos ordenado por nome</th>
               </tr>
                             <xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente">
                              <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
                             </xsl:apply-templates>
                             <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightCyan"> Critério usado abaixo: exibir os clientes da cidade do Rio de Janeiro</th>
               </tr>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[cidade='Rio de Janeiro']"/>
                 <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes do estado do RJ com ordenado pelo nome; </th>
               </tr>
                             <xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[estado='RJ']">
                              <xsl:sort select="nome" order="ascending" />
                             </xsl:apply-templates>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" bgcolor="LightYellow"> Critério usado abaixo:  exibir os clientes com crédito entre 250 e 400, em ordem descendente de crédito) </th>
               </tr>
                             <xsl:apply-templates select="informacoes/cliente[credito >250 and 400 > credito]">
                              <xsl:sort select="credito" order="descending" />
                             </xsl:apply-templates>
              </table>
            </body>
         </html>
      </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="informacoes/cliente">
             <tr>
              <td bgcolor="LightGreen"><xsl:value-of  select="nome"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of  select="telefone"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="estado"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="credito"/></td>
             </tr>
            </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice one too! I was unaware of the possibility to omit the xsl:for-each tag. Thanks Dimitre!

Comment: @user1676355, You are welcome. It is recommended to avoid using `xsl:for-each` (to use `xsl:apply-templates` instead), and this is possible in 99.999% of all cases. I am aware only of a single use-case where `xsl:for-each` is really necessary.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I'm incredibly curious: what is the one use case that you are thinking of?

Comment: @ABach, The one case is when in order to get the result of the `key()` function, one must change the current document. This is done in XSLT 1.0 using `<xsl:for-each select="document(newUrl)">`